# creating javascript Date object is not working properly

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

what is the problem and how to fix this ?

```
> new Date(2022,5,31)
< Fri Jul 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
> new Date("2022-5-31")
< Tue May 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
```

[creating Date(2022,5,31) object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZqTI.png)

Comment: @SumitSharma thanks for answering ; but i tried new  new Date("2022-05-31") and the result is 
< Tue May 31 2022 04:30:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time) {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Month is 0 indexed, i.e. 0 represents January.
When you pass in a string with explicit date formatting like "2022-5-31" the month is not 0 indexed.

```
> new Date(2022,5,31)
                ^
              June
                   ^ 
                   31 -> 01 of the next month (Jul)
< Fri Jul 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)

> new Date("2022-5-31")
                 ^
                May
                    ^
                   31 valid day
< Tue May 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
```

This becomes explicit when you try putting days of 35, for example:

```
> console.log(new Date(2022, 05, 35));
< Tue Jul 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Comment: I exactly got my answer so clearly, thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, January is `0` while in the second example, January is `1`.

June only has 30 days so the extra 31st rolls over into July.